# Changing an application core built in Java to Scala - An error and other doubts

Tags: java, eclipse, list, scala

Imagine 2 modules for an application. One is called core and acts like an API with a set of interfaces (and some functions defined).

The other module is called CoreTest and implements some classes that extend the API and tests are made in that core using JUnit.

Now I want to change only the core module to Scala. And I am a rooky at scala :).

So far I got an error:

> The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot
>   find the class file for scala.collection.immutable.List. Fix the build
>   path then try building this project   ScalaCoreTest

So that raised some doubts.

- Can I use strucutures defined by Scala for Scala?
- Should I avoid using other things in scala that can't be "translated" to Java?

I am using eclipse with scala plugin.

Comment: What IDE are you using? It sounds like there's something wrong with the setup of your IDE, so that it can't find the standard Scala library.

Comment: Eclipse. I installed scala plugin :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the standard Scala library is included in your project. Right-click the project in the Package Explorer, choose Properties, Java Build Path, Libraries.

You should see at least a JRE System Library and a Scala Library there.

Your project is probably lacking the Scala Library. Add it by clicking the "Add Library..." button on the right, select "Scala Library", and click Finish.

Comment: Ok, it was that. But Imagine that I want to provide this API to all Java programmers. There is a way to remove this dependency from scala library?

Comment: If part of your code is in Scala then you will ofcourse need the Scala library to run your program. There's no way around that.

Comment: And I can't convert it to a jar that has no dependency on the library? I mean, for a final result ofc.

Comment: Maybe you could package the content of the Scala library inside your JAR file but that's hard and ugly, it would be much easier to just add the Scala library to the classpath as one of the dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the project and select "Configure > Add Scala Nature". This will configure your build path correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the shortut to the answer provided by Jesper.