# Scala abstract classes translation into Java

Tags: java, scala, abstract-class

Scala is giving me a lot of headches lately since I can't find information on the Internet. It is hard to reach for info since Scala defines his own language (that I don't know yet) with a set of **infinite** terms.

I made some questions on StackOverflow regarding this translation between Scala and Java and in the [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033576/changing-an-application-core-built-in-java-to-scala-an-error-and-other-doubts) I said that I was going to give up this approach. However, I would like to understand what is happening.

Imagine a Scala class:

```
abstract class Block(n: String) {

    require(n != null)
    val name = n

    var log: ArrayList[String]
    var inputs: ArrayList[Input[_]]
    var outputs: ArrayList[Output[_]]

    def newValue
}
```

So far so good. The problem is:

I can't access class fields (and yes, I tried `this.inputs()`). And probably because it is translated on this:

```
public abstract class pt.thesis.tiago.Block 
    extends java.lang.Object implements  scala.ScalaObject{

    public java.lang.String name();
    public abstract java.util.ArrayList log();
    public abstract void log_$eq(java.util.ArrayList);
    public abstract java.util.ArrayList inputs();
    public abstract void inputs_$eq(java.util.ArrayList);
    public abstract java.util.ArrayList outputs();
    public abstract void outputs_$eq(java.util.ArrayList);
    public abstract void newValue();
    public pt.thesis.tiago.Block(java.lang.String);
}
```

Why every single thing is abstract? Can't I do like Java and only the things I want are abstract?

Comment: Starting with complaints and ending with something like a threat isn't a very constructive way to frame a question here.

Comment: I belive that I was missunderstood. First of all that first thing wasn't a complain. I provided info on why I am having so much dificulties. Maybe someone could say "please check this website that has a lot of good initial info for scala" and solve that. Sorry if it looked like a complain.

Second I didn't threat no one from stackoverflow. Actually I was saying that I will not bother StackOverflow users with questions regarding this subject anymore. Kinda of "I am sorry but this is the last time I ask about this subject". Probly I can refine the tone and take off some frustration of it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding material for learning Scala, I learned a lot just reading [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala), by Martin Odersky (Scala's creator), Lex Spoon and Bill Venners. Also, there's a lot of good information on [docs.scala-lang.org](http://docs.scala-lang.org/), with a pretty decent [Tour of Scala](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/tour-of-scala.html).

Regarding terminology, I don't think Scala has invented that many terms. It's possible that those terms come from languages that you're not familiar with ([Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/), [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/), [ML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_%28programming_language%29), etc.) or concepts that don't get a lot of discussion in other languages, like [type theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory).

The general principle here is that Scala is a very regular language. In fact, Martin wants to [make it simpler and more regular](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/scala-language/PV4q6O1qIh8/discussion).

In Java, only methods may be abstract. In Scala, basically any member of a class may be abstract. In Scala, to make an item abstract, you leave out it's definition. So the statement `var log: ArrayList[String]` actually creates an abstract var, **not** a concrete bar initialized with `null`. Yes, this is different than your expectations from Java. But it makes Scala as a whole a more regular language.

```
abstract class Foo {
  type SomeType               // abstract type

  val someVal: SomeType       // abstract val

  var someVar: SomeType       // abstract var

  def someMethod(v: SomeType) // abstract method
}
```

If you actually want to create a field initialized to `null`, then initialize it with `_`. That will create concrete vars instead of abstract ones.

Comment: After I accepted the other answer you came with a lot more info. Both are good answers but you covered my initial problem: Looking for info. Actually, I bought the book and already read it till page 160~ or something. I love the book. But is dense. For me, that never had contact with functional languages/terminology it requires some time to absorve all the concepts. Thanks for the extra info you provided.

Answer (score 3):

Every single thing is not abstract: name is not abstract.

In fact, as it is an abstract class, you can have some declared but undefined values, which will be themselves tagged as abstract. So if you don't want 'inputs' to be abstract, just define them:

```
var inputs = ArrayList[Input[_]]()
```

**EDIT:** About your aditional question in comments, you can still use the default value (which will be null):

```
abstract class Input[Type]{ 
  var value:Type = _; 
}
```

see [what does it mean assign "_" to a field in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040886/what-does-it-mean-assign-to-a-field-in-scala) and the excellent answer for more info.

Comment: Sorry for 2 questions on 1 mode But I was feeling that I was spamming StackOverflow. Since you only answered one probably I will separate this questions before anyone answers it :).

Comment: About your solution. That worked for most of the things. But still one left: 

If I have: `abstract class Input[Type]{ var value:Type;}` I can't initiate it with `Type()` or `null`

Comment: I see what you mean, this is a tricky question but, if you want your value to be dependent of `Type`, then this value will be different for different classes that extend this abstract class, so, this is kind of the reason why you use abstract class, isn't it?

Comment: About spamming: this website is made to ask questions, so don't fear to ask too many questions. Asking another question for problem 2 is a good idea.

Comment: The problem about declaring a field abstract is that java thinks every field of scala is a method. So, Java will ask for me to implement something like value() and my API will become a mess...

Comment: _ was a briliant ideia. Thanks :)